# position img added using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added three images by bootstrap. but these images display in left side of page, while I want them display in center of page.

How can I do it?

this is code of images and bootstrap

```
<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" root="teal" >
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="10000">
      <img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."width="1010"height="600px" >
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
      <img src="img/pic2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."width="1010"height="600px">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/pic3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."width="1010"height="600px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://code2care.org/pages/center-align-image-bootstrap/), you can use bootstrap's `.center-block` css class to center align an image.

You would insert it into your `<img>` tag like so:

```
<img class=".center-block">
```